# NetworkX recursive child nodes

Tags: python, recursion, nodes, networkx

Using the latest NetworkX ([version 1.11](https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) at the time of writing), what is the most efficient way of retrieving all (recursive) child nodes for a given node?
The `successors()` function retrieves the immediate children and in previous versions there was [`dfs_preorder_nodes solution`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/networkx-discuss/SukXT4ZHrRk).

Comment: What's wrong with `dfs_preorder_nodes`?

Comment: Ahh my bad! I could only find this for previous versions, until now. For some reason thought the newest version has classes and class-based methods. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

there is descendants method which will find all children nodes, including children of every child:

> ```
> 1-2
>  \
>   3
>    \
>     4
> ```

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(1, 3)
G.add_edge(2, 4)
res = nx.descendants(G, 1)
print (res) #{2,3,4}
```

Answer (score 0):

dfs_preorder_nodes is still valid in the latest version as pointed out by Joel. The documentation is available [here](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/algorithms.traversal.html).

The following achieves the desired, i.e. all recursive children for a node of interest:

```
import networkx as nx 
children = [node for node in nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(network, queryID)]`
```

Comment: You could also do `children = list(nx.dfs...)` to turn the generator into a list.